# Github Actions - Make job wait for separate action to complete

Tags: github-actions

I have 2 github actions workflows in the same repo:

- Workflow A builds one docker image, triggered on a push to `/forms`
- Workflow B builds a different app, triggered on a push to any path except `/forms`
- Workflow B contains integration tests that rely on what's deployed from both workflow A and workflow B.

A and B can both change independently, or together. If just A changes or just B changes my current setup is fine. But if both A and B change, how can I ensure that the integration tests running in workflow B won't run until workflow A is complete?